# how to add home icon instead of text in wordpress menu

Tags: menus, homepage, icon

i need to add "home.png" icon image as home button instead of text for example
[image]

i searched this question in google and find out a way, but that didn't work. the method mentioned in those sites are

1. enable css class in screen options in apperance>>menu
2. write a class "home-icon"
3. in style.css insert this class. i wrote the code as

   .home-icon{
     background-image:url(images/home.png);
       }

i followed this [site](http://premium.wpmudev.org/blog/wordpress-custom-menu-icons/)
but this didn't work for me. what is the problem in this method? or any other alternative ideas?

Comment: Did you put a respective icon `home.png` in the images folder?

Comment: yeah..it is in the images folder inside my theme folder

Comment: Then can you check with a tool like firebug, if you really are getting the image or not,  and also check the permission of the image

Comment: i'm not getting the image. but the class "home-icon" is showing with other classes of home menu.

Comment: View the page, then view source and copy the URL of the home.png image. Paste that into your browser and see if you get the image, otherwise you might have an error in your path

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i solved the problem by using a plugin named [nav-menu images](http://wordpress.org/plugins/nav-menu-images/)

Answer (score 1):

to hide "HOME" label from wordpress navigation i use

```
//change 105 with your home id
 #menu-item-105 span {
 display:none;
 }
```

and for icon i use "Iconic Navigation" wordpress plugin